# Applying Events Handler to Child Elements (Event Propogation in jQuery)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

***Edit :*** Problem wasn't related Event Propagation, if you want to know how to stop propagation in jQuery, then use `event.stopPropagation();`

When user moves his/her mouse over `<span>` element my jQuery code appends an `<img>`into this `<span>` element and when he moves out his mouse off `<span>` than the element appended is removed. It helps people to edit the field when clicking on the appended `<img>` element.

The reason I used `append()` method to add `<img>` into `<span>` is because I want to keep `<img>` element visible when user moves his mouse over to appended `<img>` element *(`<img>` is becoming `<span>`'s child element)* But it didn't happen and when user moves his mouse over it `<img>` is being deleted. I am thinking it is because event propagation but I couldn't find how to activate it in jQuery as we do with `addEventListener` in Firefox based browsers.

Here is the code :

**JQuery Code :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.EditEnabled').bind("mouseover", ShowEditFields);
    $(".EditEnabled").bind("mouseout", HideEditFields);
});

function ShowEditFields(event) {    
    $(event.target).append(" <img id='editImg' src='images/edit.png' style='margin-bottom:-3px'/>");
}

function HideEditFields(event) {
    $(event.target).children("#editImg").remove();
}
```

**Simple HTML :**

```
<span id="something" class="EditEnabled">Something Here</span>
```

Can you explain my how to solve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the jQuery `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, not `mousover` and `mouseout`. The reason is that `mouseout` will fire when you move the mouse over the `img`.

Thankfully, jQuery combines this into a `hover` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.EditEnabled').hover(ShowEditFields, HideEditFields);
});
```

**However** I agree with the other answer that you should use CSS to do this vs. manipulating the DOM. I would just use the `:hover` pseudo selector, and then add special support for IE6.

**CSS**

```
span.EditEnabled img { display: none }
span.EditEnabled:hover img,
span.EditEnabled.hover img { display: block }
```

*Make sure you have the img in the span in your HTML to begin with, and that is all you need for most browsers and IE7+*

To support IE6 add:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $(".EditEnabled").hover(
    function(){ $(this).addClass('hover') },
    function(){ $(this).removeClass('hover')}
  );
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would avoid as much DOM manipulation as you can. The ideal scenario is to construct your markup like this:

```
<span class="editEnabled">Some data<img ...></span>
```

with CSS:

```
span.editEnabled img { display: none; }
span.editEnabled img.visible { display: inline; }
```

and Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("span.editEnabled").hover(function() {
    $(this).children("img").addClass("visible");
  }, function() {
    $(this).children("img").removeClass("visible");
  });
});
```

That should pretty much do it.

I would avoid the jQuery effects as making things visible will make them block level elements rather than inline like you want.

Comment: Thanks but could you tell me the reason why you would avoid DOM Manipulation ? I know it is not related to main question but I would like to know if you don't mind.

Comment: DOM manipulation is expensive, processor-wise. That's why you should just show/hide whenever possible

Comment: Depending on the browser, DOM manipulation is expensive. Think about it: the browser may have to figure out how to render the document (again). It can also cause memory leaks if done to excess on certain browsers.

Comment: I appreciated your answer but could you also show the way I wanted above please ? I like to see that way ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another answer actually, the way I am looking for. It might not be a best practice but at least I've found out how to solve that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //    $('.EditEnabled').bind("mouseenter", ShowEditFields);
    //    $(".EditEnabled").bind("mouseleave", HideEditFields);
    $(".EditEnabled").hover(ShowEditFields, HideEditFields);
});

function ShowEditFields(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is(":has(#editImg)") == false)
        target.append(" <img id='editImg' src='images/edit.png' style='margin-bottom:-3px;display:inline'></img>");
}

function HideEditFields(event) {
    //    event.stopPropagation();
    //    if ($(event.relatedTarget).is("#editImg") == false)
    $(event.target).children("#editImg").remove();
}
```

Comment: @Aaron, my solution is far simpler than yours, did you try it? (The top part)

Comment: @Doug Neiner : Yeap, yours way better and I am gonna use it but I also wanted to know how to do things in hard way :)